# Move an object after baking normals

Tags: transforms, normals

I'm a new Blender user and I'm facing my first big issue.

I've just baked high poly normals to a low poly object successfully after a night of tutorials reading, but now, whenever I try to move the low poly object, normals won't follow the low poly object in space.

What should i do if i need to move any object that i've baked avoiding this issue ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sKxS.jpg here is my node setting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRpyc.jpg here is what happens whenever i try to move the low poly object affected by the baked normals

Did I miss something during the baking or anything ? I've noticed whenever I disconnect the normal node, the normals stays active but nothing changes and I'm still not able to move it without this awful result.

Comment: hello, please show your node setup, you need to use the Texture Coordinate "UV" output socket

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue and I feel stupid now but maybe someone will feel like me one day so here is what happened : Before I bake normals, I add a modifier on my low poly (shrinkwrap) and I forgot to shut it down... :p